# Failed to install pip for pypy on Ubuntu

Tags: python, ubuntu, pip, pypy, linode

I cannot install pip for pypy 4.0.1 on Ubuntu 15.10.

I downloaded pypy 4.0.1 from http://pypy.org/download.html. Created a symlink for it. And used wget to download get-pip.py from https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py.

But when I ran `sudo pypy get-pip.py`, I got exception:

```
Collecting pip
Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "/tmp/tmps2kjCI/pip.zip/pip/basecommand.py", line 211, in main
      status = self.run(options, args)
    File "/tmp/tmps2kjCI/pip.zip/pip/commands/install.py", line 294, in run
      requirement_set.prepare_files(finder)
    File "/tmp/tmps2kjCI/pip.zip/pip/req/req_set.py", line 334, in prepare_files
      functools.partial(self._prepare_file, finder))
    File "/tmp/tmps2kjCI/pip.zip/pip/req/req_set.py", line 321, in _walk_req_to_install
      more_reqs = handler(req_to_install)
    File "/opt/pypy-4.0.1-linux64/lib_pypy/_functools.py", line 42, in __call__
      return self._func(*(self._args + fargs), **fkeywords)
    File "/tmp/tmps2kjCI/pip.zip/pip/req/req_set.py", line 491, in _prepare_file
      session=self.session)
    File "/tmp/tmps2kjCI/pip.zip/pip/download.py", line 825, in unpack_url
      session,
    File "/tmp/tmps2kjCI/pip.zip/pip/download.py", line 673, in unpack_http_url
      from_path, content_type = _download_http_url(link, session, temp_dir)
    File "/tmp/tmps2kjCI/pip.zip/pip/download.py", line 885, in _download_http_url
      with open(file_path, 'wb') as content_file:
    TypeError: expected string, got NoneType object
```

I could run `sudo python get-pip.py` without problem but failed with pypy. I also tried Ubuntu 12.04 and 14.04 but no luck.

I have Python 2.7.10 installed and I'm using a Linode machine. But changed to a DigitalOcean one didn't help.

Comment: Python 2.7 comes with pip installed

Comment: Yes but PyPy doesn't. I was trying to install pip for PyPy.

Comment: Hmm. [According to the documentation](http://doc.pypy.org/en/latest/install.html) I don't see anything wrong with what you've done other than Ubuntu 15.10 isn't listed on the pypy site as being built against

Comment: The thing is even with absolute path it still failed.

Comment: OK. Seems like downgrading PyPy to 2.7.0 solves this problem for now. But it would be really helpful if someone can point out why the latest PyPy doesn't work.

Comment: Works for me (same Ubuntu 15.10 and same PyPy 4.0.1 on 64-bit Linux)...

Comment: You could also try `pypy -m ensurepip`, which works like it does in the recent variants of CPython 2.7.x

Answer (score 1):

How about installing PyPy from the Ubuntu archives `sudo apt install pypy`. Or if you want the latest version, from the [PyPy PPA](https://launchpad.net/%7Epypy/+archive/ubuntu/ppa/)

Then if you create a virtualenv, it will have pip inside it:

```
$ sudo apt-get install virtualenv
$ virtualenv -p pypy ve
$ source ./ve/bin/activate
$ pip install ...
```

Comment: You don't need a particular PyPy to use virtualenv in this way; these commands should work with any PyPy.

Comment: No, that was intentionally `apt`. The question was posed as being on Ubuntu 15.04, which has the new, pretty, `apt` command.

Comment: Well, on ubuntu 16.04, this will crash when creating the virtuelenv.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, and the solution is easy, yo have to run this command:

```
export LC_ALL=C.UTF-8
```

And then run the pip installation.

You should add this line to your .bashrc or .bash_profile in the server, even you can add it to /etc/environment to have it in a global way. (If someone has a better solution, please tell me)

**Edit (2016-10):**

Above is the global and lazy solution for any other distribution.
If you're in ubuntu, you need to reconfigure the locales and you can do it with:

```
sudo locale-gen "en_US.UTF-8"
sudo dpkg-reconfigure locales
```

Comment: Can you explain what this solution does?

Comment: Well, i don't remember why (almost 7 month ago), but when you have a fresh install of ubuntu server you have to configure the locale, this parameters are used by many applications to determine the encoding and another things. Answer edited to add ubuntu commands.